# Is any possible preview or run that particular program only in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

Can anyone tell me, Some modify or update in my android program, Is any possible in eclipse, preview option or run that particular program and view that output only. Because I run emulator it takes more time. So that why I am asking. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking whether you could modify your code to run in Eclipse as opposed to emulating an Android system and running it on that.

Well, yes, you could (probably) change your code so it runs 'in Eclipse', however why would you do that? Then you don't know if it runs on Android which is what you aim to run it on.

That would be defeating the purpose of developing on Android in the first place. That's what the emulator is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Because I run emulator it takes more time. So that why I am asking.
```

to save time

```
 1- upgrade the eclipse to latest one so you can see the ui changes in XML in eclipse it self (XML in graphic mode)
 2- not restart the emulator every time just close app in emulator and run from eclipse
 3- do not use debug just run to launch app
 4- if can attach the device and run on that it will faster than emulator
```